# TypeError: _web3modal_standalone__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web3js, web3modal

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!walletConnected) {
    Web3ModalRef.current = new Web3Modal({
      network: "goerli",
      providerOptions: {},
      disableInjectedProvider: false,
    });
    connectWallet();
  }
}, [walletConnected]);
```

I've tried downloading the web3modal package multiple ways, rewrote the whole thing a couple of times but still can't figure my way past this issue.